# How do i get this Basic Authentication working in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, basic-authentication, authorize-attribute

I am using `Basic Authentication` and I have created a `Middleware` for this. When I use the `Authorize` attribute and try to make an API call through Postman, i get `401 Unauthorize` even as I am added the authorization details in Postman.

I am not sure if it is the way i am calling the controller action via postman or whether I am missing a header option in postman.

**ConfigureServices**

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddBasicAuthentication(GetBasicAuthenticationOptions(users));
```

**Configure**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("SiteCorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

**Basic Authentication Implementation**

```
    private Action<BasicAuthenticationOptions> GetBasicAuthenticationOptions(IList<UserConfiguration> users)
    {
        return options =>
        {
            options.Realm = "Public API";
            options.Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                {
                    var authenticatedUser = users.FirstOrDefault(u =>
                        u.Username == context.UserName && u.Password == context.Password);

                    if (authenticatedUser != null)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,
                                context.UserName,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                        };

                        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                            BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
                        context.Principal = principal;

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authentication failed."));
                }
            };
        };
    }
```

**Controller Action with Authorize**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Json("yes");
    }
```

**Postman request**

The username and passwords are in the appsettings.json file

[image]

Comment: You say you've created middleware for this, but you haven't included any middleware code here. Are you using [idunno.Authentication](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication) or have you built your own?

Comment: @KirkLarkin the services.AddAuthentication is the middleware code, and in the Configure method in the Startup.cs, there is a UseAuthentication in there

Comment: *Don't* do that! You are storing and comparing *unhashed passwords*! Use ASP.NET Core's own mechanisms instead. This code almost guarantees you or your customer's site will be breached

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is not the question i am asking though, the question is why is the authentication not working, regardless of whether the password is hashed or not, the authentication mechanism is returning 401 not authorised.

Comment: Although it's not related to the question you're asking, you will find that a lot of SO users will not want to help you write such insecure code.

Comment: @ifelabolz Kirk Larkin already answered that in a roundabout way. Don't create your own. Use a provider like [idunno.Authentication](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/tree/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Basic). The author is on .NET's security team, and he *does* say "You really shouldn't do this". This way you'll avoid problems in the middleware itself and only have to contend with secure password storage and validation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos firstly if you look at the stuff in the dependancy injection method and you look at idunno's implementation you'll see that this is the AspNetCore BasicAuthentication, not something I created.

Comment: @ifelabolz it isn't. There's no `AddBasicAuthentication` method in .NET Core 2.0, it was *removed* precisely because it's unsuitable. Blowdart addes his own extension method, [AddBasic](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/blob/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Basic/BasicAuthenticationExtensions.cs#L16). If that is your code, did you try *debugging* it? Does execution enter the validation delegate? Where is the code for `AddBasicAuthentication` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic

Comment: @ifelabolz if you don't provide all the code or don't mention the package you use, it's impossible to try and reproduce. In any case, did you try *debugging* ? What does this code do, how does it behave? Are you saying *that package* has a bug? Were you able to run the Test project in that repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was just because `app.UseMvc();` was placed before `app.UseAuthentication();` . I just had to place `app.UseMvc();` after `app.UseAuthentication();` and that fixed it.